# PHP foreach format with 2 foreach statements

Tags: php, foreach

I would like to ask if my code is correct.

I have these 2 explode commands:

```
$url = 'http://google.com, http://yahoo.com, http://msn.com, http://yahoo.com, http://msn.com, http://yahoo.com, http://msn.com';
$key = 'google, yahoo, msn';
$xurl = explode( ',', $url );
$xkey = explode( ',', $key );

foreach ( $xurl as $hyperlink ) {
    foreach ( $xkey as $keyword )
    $sqlHyperLink = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO jon_hyperlink VALUE( '', '$hyperlink', '$keyword', NOW() )" ) or die ( mysql_error() );
}
    echo 'Hyperlink Created';
```

***UPDATE****
If you'll notice, the `$url` variable has 7 url's listed and I have 3 keywords.  How can I make the keyword repeatedly...

How can I insert the string with one `foreach` because I used 2 `foreach` for my query and it inserted it 2 times. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: other than mysql_* function that should be replaced with PDO , it looks good to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
$xurl = explode( ',', $url );
$xkey = explode( ',', $key );

$assoc = array_combine($xkey, $xurl);

foreach ($assoc as $keyword => $hyperlink) {
    //insert here
}
```

Comment: hi i got error with the code you said `Both parameters should have an equal number of elements in`

Comment: @user1538668 You must be sure that both arrays have the same number of elements (in your example there must be the same `,` in both of your strings)

Comment: yes but T_T im sorry i update the post, i need to put 10 url for example then only 3 keyword, then these 3 keyword should be repeatedly for this 10url...

Comment: @user1538668 Change `array_combine($xkey, $xurl);` with `array_combine($xkey, array_unique($xurl));`

Answer (score 0):

Hammer down the arrays using an index.

```
$numItems = count($xurl);
for ($i=0; $i<$numItems; $i++) {
    $sqlHyperLink = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO jon_hyperlink VALUE( '', '{$xurl[$i]}', '{$xkey   [$i]}', NOW() )" ) or die ( mysql_error() ); 
}
```

Ideally check out PDO where you can bind the values to a prepared query - its faster, safer and better practice, though!

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'http://google.com, http://yahoo.com, http://msn.com, http://yahoo.com, http://msn.com, http://yahoo.com, http://msn.com';
$key = 'google, yahoo, msn';
$xurl = explode( ',', $url );
$xkey = explode( ',', $key );

foreach ($xurl as $i => $keyword) {
    $sqlHyperLink = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO jon_hyperlink VALUE( '', '{$xkey[$i]}', '$keyword', NOW() )" ) or die ( mysql_error() );
}
```

Comment: there are lots of error... `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Answer (score 0):

If your $url and $key map together in the correct order you can just use a simple for loop with an index and access both arrays for each loop.

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($key); $i++)
{
    mysql_query("insert ... $key[$i] .. $url[$i] ..");
}
```